# AWS RDS Cluster CLI Command That Returns Instance Class Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, amazon-aurora

I'm looking for an AWS RDS CLI command that will return Instance Class value for an Aurora instance in a cluster ? Please let know if anyone know what this is because I can't find it. You would think this would be apart of the [describe-db-clusters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-clusters.html)

I'm trying to return the **db.t2.medium** value from the AWS RDS CLI.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [describe-db-instances](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) can help if we pass `db-instance-identifier` , you want get this from cluster id?

Comment: Thank I see now, You need to use the describe-db-instances command to get the instance values. Thank You!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Cluster details we can use [describe-db-clusters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-clusters.html):

> aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier
> my-cluster

To get Instance details we can use [describe-db-instances](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html):

> aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier my-instance-one --query 'DBInstances[].DBInstanceClass'

To get all instance details using cluster identifier, we can execute `describe-db-instances` for every instance returned by `describe-db-clusters`

> aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier
> my-cluster | jq -r
> ".DBClusters[].DBClusterMembers[].DBInstanceIdentifier" | xargs -I {}
> aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier {} --query
> 'DBInstances[].{Intance:DBInstanceIdentifier, Class:DBInstanceClass}'

Comment: --query 'DBInstances[].DBInstanceClass' is returning `null` for Aurora RDS cluster. How to get instance type for aurora postgres ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux and bash you can write basic for loop to get the class of each instance in an aurora cluster. Combination of [describe-db-clusters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-clusters.html) and [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) is used.

```
cluster_id="database-1"

for db_id in $(aws rds describe-db-clusters \
            --db-cluster-identifier ${cluster_id} \
            --query 'DBClusters[0].DBClusterMembers[].DBInstanceIdentifier' \
            --output text); do


  db_instance_class=$(aws rds describe-db-instances \
        --db-instance-identifier ${db_id} \
        --query 'DBInstances[0].DBInstanceClass'\
        --output text)
       
  echo "${db_id}: ${db_instance_class}"

done
```

The example result is:

```
database-1-instance-1-ap-southeast-2c: db.t2.small
database-1-instance-1: db.t2.small
```

Comment: Does this still work?  My serverless Aurora db is up and running answering queries, but the "DBClusterMembers" value is an empty set.